# How to create setter with a trait as parameter

Tags: rust

Just started with Rust. Would like to create a setter that will accept trait as param.
To illustrate idea

```
pub trait Engine {
  fn start() -> bool;
}

struct Car {
  engine: Box<dyn Engine>,
}

impl Car {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    let engine = Box::new(DummyEngine {});
    Self {
      engine,
    }
  }
  pub fn set_engine(&mut self, engine: &dyn Engine) {
      self.engine = Box::new(engine);
  }
}
```

The setter code complains:

```
the trait bound `&dyn Engine: Engine` is not satisfied
required for the cast to the object type `dyn Engine` rustcE0277
```

Also, how can the dummy default engine be avoided? Let's say a car doesn't need an engine. Should it be wrapped in an `Option`?

Comment: Does your `DummyEngine` implement the `Engine` trait?

Comment: For the setter, why you don't pass a Box and then clone it. Your struct accept a `Box<dyn Engine>` not a `Box<&dyn Engine>`.

Comment: Your code as written results in a different error.

Comment: Given that `engine: &dyn Engine` is a reference to engine, then `Box::new(engine)` will be `Box<& dyn Engine>` not `Box<dyn Engine>` which are two different types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following `Engine` trait that specifies `start()` as method instead of an associated function:

```
pub trait Engine {
  fn start(&mut self) -> bool;
}
```

Your `DummyEngine` doesn't look to implement the `Engine` trait. You could just implement `Engine` for `DummyEngine`:

```
struct DummyEngine;

impl Engine for DummyEngine {
  fn start(&mut self) -> bool { false }
}
```

This approach – i.e., using a dummy object – would correspond to the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). However, you could go for `Option` instead, as you suggested, and define `Car` as:

```
struct Car {
  engine: Option<Box<dyn Engine>>,
}
```

This way, you could implement `new()` and `set_engine()` as:

```
impl Car {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    Car {
      engine: None,
    }
  }

  pub fn set_engine(&mut self, engine: Box<dyn Engine>) {
    self.engine = Some(engine);
  }
}
```

You will be passing a `Box<dyn Engine>` to `set_engine()` by value. The `Box` owns the `Engine`, and it will be moved into the `engine` field. That is, the `Box` argument passed is moved into the parameter `engine` and, this is, in turn, moved into the `engine` field of `Car`.

---

As `Car::new()` doesn't take any arguments, you may want to implement the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait for `Car` as well:

```
impl Default for Car {
   fn default() -> Self {
      Car::new()
   }
}
```